# What's the Java's float.floatToRawIntBits equivalent method in C#?

Tags: c#, java

What's the Java's float.floatToRawIntBits method implementation in C# ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the Java version correctly it should be:

```
        float value = 123.23F;

        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

        int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

This puts the bytes representing the float into an integer.

Alternatively, a more complex (but probably faster) way to do it is to create a struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct FloatToIntConverter
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int IntValue;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public float FloatValue;
    }

        FloatToIntConverter converter = new FloatToIntConverter();
        converter.FloatValue = value;
        int result2 = converter.IntValue;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you.